# Unable to use a private image from dockerhub in bitbucket pipelines

Tags: docker, bitbucket-pipelines, dockerhub

I have been unable to use my private image which has been successfully pushed to docker hub in my bitbucket pipelines. The build step fails without giving a specific error log.

```
image:
  name: reponame/imagename
  username: $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME
  password: $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
  email: $DOCKER_HUB_EMAIL
pipelines:
  default:
      - step:
          name: Code linting test
          script:
            - echo "Working"
```

where in the  original code `reponame/imagename` are substituted with my account name and private image name. My username, password, and email variables have been configured both as repository and workspace variables, and to test whether the configurations are working I have tried

```
image: python:3.8
pipelines:
  default:
      - step:
          name: Code linting test
          script:
            - echo $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME, $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD, $DOCKER_HUB_EMAIL
```

by using the default python image which has successfully outputted the results. I have also tried defining the image and variables not at the global but at the step level using `-pipe:` but again with no success. Any help will be appreciated.